# Regex - Split terms using the term "xx"

Tags: javascript, json, regex

When the user inputs a term into an input bar it is split into an array if the term matches what's on my json list.  For example if the user inputs something like "st.mp, st.mp, fireball" the array becomes `["mp",",","mp",",","fireball"]`. The commas are also included which is on purpose.  Each term creates an image in my app.

I need the term "xx" to be captured. Commas and "xx" are supposed to separate the terms. They are supposed to work the same way.  If I enter something like "st.mp xx fireball" it should return `["mp","xx","fireball"]`.

Right now my regex is `(\w+( \w+)*|\s)` I can get terms with spaces in them (for example if I enter "red fireball" it returns `["red fireball"]`)  I'm not sure what to add to capture "xx".  I think what's happening is that when I enter a term like "st.mp xx fireball" it's capturing the entire thing and it doesn't match with anything in my json.  I'm still new to regex.  The things I've tried range from just doing `(xx)` to `\b(xx)` I'm kind of just lost on what to even try.

Comment: Is it required that you only use Regex matches? Could you use the Javascript .split() function?

Comment: I am using .split() with regex matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-line demo:

```
"st.mp xx fireball, with space".split(/(?:(,)\s+|\s+(xx)\s+)/)
// -> ["st.mp", undefined, "xx", "fireball", ",", undefined, "with space"]
// filter undefined out then
```

You might using `.split` in a wrong direction: the param of `.split` should be splitters